# What is the weight limit for a Cube Aim Pro 2021?

Tags: mountain-bike, weight

My Cube Aim Pro 2021 model is being delivered this upcoming Saturday. I'm really happy about it because there was a huge run on mountain bikes, it will be my first.

Now my concern is I'm quite heavy (119kg) and [this PDF file](https://www.cube.eu/fileadmin/2021/Service/Systemgewicht/Bikes_weight_limits_MY20_21.pdf) says for my hardtail Aim (I got the Pro but that one is not on the list) that a rider weight + bike weight should be not more than 115kg, so I'm way over that.  But on the right it says that the weight limit is 140kg (then I should be good right?)

Now I'm wondering, what is it? And yes I know I'm way too heavy but that's why I'm getting an MTB, I'm going to start with riding gravel roads, no jumps or anything (I live in the Netherlands).

Should I just cancel the whole bike or just ride it? I'm really not sure if it's 115kg max or 140kg max.

---

Okay! I will only be adding a front and back mudguard, for the rest I won't be adding anything. The 115 is for the bike+rider and the extra 25kg is for lets say a backpack or a kickstand? And that makes 140kg but I wont be adding any cargo backpack or kickstand, only the mudguards.

What would you do? Cancel the bike or just use it because I don't want to destroy it in like a month of riding.

Answer (score 3):

From personal experience: The #1 thing you're going to 'destroy in like a month of riding trails' as a heavier rider is the rear wheel.  As soon as one spoke gets a bit out of tolerance the whole thing starts to come apart and go wildly out of true very quickly.

The frame might only last 7 years instead of 10, maybe crank arms and spindle will wear out in 3 years instead of 4 etc etc. but it's almost certainly the 32H rear wheel that is driving the uniform 115kg stated rider+bike limit across the entire product line of different types of frames.

A mid-range Cube would seem to be in the range where it's "worth" upgrading with a sturdier 36H wheel and would still come out cheaper than a specialty bike like a Surly that comes with them standard.  (and one assumes decent wheel builders aren't that hard to find in the Netherlands...)

(You may also just get the stock wheel re-laced with sturdier spokes, but if you're paying all that labor to have it re-laced anyway, the hub and rim aren't super expensive...)

Answer (score 1):

140kg is the absolute maximum, while 115 is the maximum you should budget for in case you want to add cargo as well. You couldn’t, for example, put 130kg of bike + rider (even though that’s less than 140kg!) and then 25kg of cargo on top, because that would be 155kg, which is over the 140kg hard limit.

Do be aware than even though you’re not officially over the limit, you’ll still wear the bike out faster than a lighter rider would.